# How to keep Chronometer running on Listview after back is pressed or App has been closed?

Tags: java, android, listview, chronometer, android-timer

I managed to add a chronometer on ListView with a start and stop button and all are working fine, but when I press back or I close the application Chronometer values are reset to 00:00. I need to let it continuing counting even if the app is closed until I come back and I stop it. If anyone knows how to do it his/her help will be appreciated.

[image: Listview Items how look like]

The following is ListviewAdapter

```
     ...............

             viewHolder = new Holder();
          LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_timing_list_adapter_view, parent, false);

        viewHolder.payment_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.paymId);
        viewHolder.history_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.histId);
        viewHolder.drivernames = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drivername);
        viewHolder.plateno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plateno);
        viewHolder.parkingname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pname);
        viewHolder.phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phonNo);
        viewHolder.chronometer = (Chronometer) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        viewHolder.button_start = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        viewHolder.button_leave = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button6);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHelper(getContext());

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    viewHolder.drivernames.setText(paymentTiming_items.getDriverFullName());
    viewHolder.plateno.setText(paymentTiming_items.getPlateNo());
    viewHolder.parkingname.setText(paymentTiming_items.getParkName());
    viewHolder.payment_id.setText(paymentTiming_items.getPaymentId());
    viewHolder.history_id.setText(paymentTiming_items.getHistoryId());

    viewHolder.phone.setText(paymentTiming_items.getDriverPhone());


    viewHolder.chronometer.setText(paymentTiming_items.getChronoTime());
    // Start chronometer on button click
    viewHolder.button_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewHolder.chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            viewHolder.chronometer.start();
      // Toast.makeText(getContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("My POSITION", "" + position);

        }
    });
    // Stop chronometer on button click
    viewHolder.button_leave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String paymentID = viewHolder.payment_id.getText().toString();
            String historyId = viewHolder.history_id.getText().toString();
            String driver_phonenumber = viewHolder.phone.getText().toString();

            viewHolder.chronometer.stop();
            time_parked = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - viewHolder.chronometer.getBase();


            time_parked = (time_parked / 1000) / 60;
            Log.d("time elapsed", "" + time_parked);

   ..............
```

**Main activity which shows the List View**

```
        .........................


         private void FindDriver_Timing(final String custodian_id) {
      // Tag used to cancel the request
       String tag_string_req = "req_Verfication";
       progressBarList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Urls.payementUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "cerfication Response: " + response.toString());
              JSONArray jsonArrayResult ;
            // Parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                try {

                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {

                    List<PaymentTiming_Items> getAllDiverDetails = new 
                ArrayList<PaymentTiming_Items>();


                        jsonArrayResult = jObj.getJSONArray("user");

                        for(int x=0; x<jsonArrayResult.length();x++) {

                            JSONObject json = 
                jsonArrayResult.getJSONObject(x);

                            String driver_fullname = 
              json.getString("driver_fullname");
                            String driver_phonenumber = 
              json.getString("driver_phonenumber");
                            String plate_no = json.getString("plate_no");
                            String parking_name = 
                  json.getString("parking_name");
                            String historyId = json.getString("historyId");
                            String paymentId  = json.getString("paymentId");


                                PaymentTiming_Items timingItems = new 
                             PaymentTiming_Items();
                                timingItems.setPlateNo(plate_no);
                                timingItems.setParkingName(parking_name);

            timingItems.setDriverFullName(driver_fullname);
                                timingItems.setHistoryId(historyId);
                                timingItems.setPaymentId(paymentId);
                                timingItems.setDriverphone(driver_phonenumber);

                                getAllDiverDetails.add(timingItems); // store all drivers' info to

                                userList =  new ArrayList<>(getAllDiverDetails);

                                ShowListData();


                        }

                        progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }

                    else{

                          // Error in login. Get the error message
                          // hiding the progress bar
                        progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + 
        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //                     // hiding the progress bar
                    progressBarList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        .........................
```

Comment: Save the previous time in storage probably in `SharedPreference` and next time start it from (last saved time+ time has been passed) . Its better if you involve server for time . Cause device time can changed manually .

Comment: ADM's answer is how you should implement it. You can also use  Service if you need to send notification after a specific time has passed.